# How to insert a string in a path in C++?

Tags: c++, string

So, I made a program in C++ that opens CMD and uses the ping command. How can I make the user to insert the IP and use it?
Idea to make it clearer:

```
string IP;
cin >> IP;      
system("C:\\Windows\\System32\\ping " IP " -t -l 65000");
```

What isn't right? It should use the CMD command "ping -t -l" and the IP the person entered.

Comment: There should be a chapter in your C++ book that explains how to use `std::string`s. How to combine them. How to get a C-style string that can be passed to C library functions like `system()`. Back when I learned this stuff, there was no stackoverflow.com, so the only way for me to figure out the same kind of things is to continue reading whatever book I was reading back then to learn C++. Maybe you should try that approach, too. Learning how to read technical documentation is a required skill for every C++ developer.

Answer (score 0):

various methods can do this

most simple that I can think of:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string IP;
    cin >> IP;
    string s = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\ping ";
    system((s + IP + " -t -l 65000").c_str());
}
```

which uses the string class of C++
c_str() is a member function that converts a C++ string object to the C representation `const char*`

The following is also possible:

using C function snprintf

using stringstream

Comment: I would mention `snprintf` instead of `strcat`